# How to add .pfx file to component RestClient

Tags: delphi, rest-client

Good morning, I'm new to the forum, I'm trying to add a certificate with pfx extension to Rest component and be able to consume an API, using delphi with RestClient, RestRequest and RestResponse components. If it is not possible such you can guide me with another Solution.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What exactly is not possible? Where's the code you used so far? Are you aware that a PFX file most likely contains text which could be parsed by you yourself?

Comment: Hello AmigoJack, I did not put any code because I do not see any property that the file receives, it is not something that does not work for me but something that I do not know how to do.

Comment: As far as i am aware a certificate (pfx) does not contain a interface definition. Until now i used the Certificates to Install / trust them on the Operating System. Definition/Documentation of rest Apis is done with swagger or open api Files. Perhaps some REST Tools have support to create Delphi Structures from a swagger /open api File.

Answer (score 0):

```
            var cert2 = new X509Certificate2(@"*****CertBundle.pfx", "***");

            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;



            RestSharp.RestClient client = new RestSharp.RestClient(new Uri(""));
            //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

            client.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection() { cert2 };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).